# Square brackets [] in react this.state is undefined and the data is not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to get the data from the database to react component and display it. This is the code I have implemented.

But it is showing as `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` in the alert. Then I checked the `Org: []` and it is showing as `undefined`.

This is the code I have implemented.

```
import axios from 'axios';

class OrganizingCommittee extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        org: []
    }
};

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:6060/orgCommittee/viewOrganizingCommittee')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({ org: response.data.data });
        }).catch(error => {
            alert(error.message);
            console.log("org",org);
        })

};


render() {
    return (
        <div>
            
            <div>
                <div className="d-flex p-2" style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '300px' }}>
                    <h1 tag='div' className='display-1 pb-3 mb-3 border-bottom'>Organizing Committee</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div className="card card border border-light shadow-0 mb-3" style={{ maxWidth: '120rem', margin: 'auto', padding: '10px' }}>
                    <div className="card-body" >
                        <div class="row">
                            {this.state.org.length > 0 && this.state.org.map((item, index) => {
                                <div class="col-sm-6 mb-5" key={index}>
                                    {item.name}
                                </div>
                            })}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br></br>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    );
}
}export default OrganizingCommittee;
```

The URL is correct and the data of it is this =>

```
[{"_id":"60c39197cf950b2e7c51e774","name":"Sample 2","image":"C:\\fakepath\\824b877bf4c731e3fcc13a8881c3e982.jpg","department":"Faculty of Computing","description":"Sample 2","status":"Post","date":"2021-06-11","createdAt":"2021-06-11T16:38:47.974Z","updatedAt":"2021-06-11T16:38:47.974Z","__v":0}]
```

The heading is showing but the data is not rendering. Can someone help me to solve this and show the data in the json array.

current output
[image: Current output]

Please don't give a minus. I have tried everything I know to find a solution to this. But still couldn't. That's why I am asking.

[image: undefined]

[image: Console]

Comment: Sure that it's `response.data.data` and not just `response.data`?

Comment: @Thomas I tried that too. But still the data is not rendering

Comment: Ok, then did you check what your server returns? What's the format of the response?

Comment: The fact that the alert is being fired means that your api is throwing an error with message `Cannot read property length of undefined`.  Your react code looks fine. So you need to debug your api server to find out the reason it's throwing this error

Comment: `undefined` and `undefined[]` are two very different things

Comment: @SakisTsalk agter adding `this.state?.org?.length > 0 ` the error is gone. But I don't know why the data is not rendering

Comment: The data probably isn't what you think it is. And there's probably an easy way with console.log or similar techniques (or even just looking at your network tab) to know how to extract your target data from teh result.

Comment: Console and network tabs are showing nothing. That's why I am unable to solve this alone

Comment: Can you please `console.log('response' + response);` inside the `.then()` and `console.log('error' + error)`; inside the `catch()` method.

Comment: @SakisTsalk I did as you told and the screen shot is added to the question. The is no error showing. Only response is showing.

Comment: Are you sure response.data.data will be an array? Try to debug and find the type of it

Comment: @PratyushNarain plese see the console output I have added last. It is an array

Comment: assginging`response.data` instead  of `response.data.data` in your state object should be correct. but you've tried that already right?

Comment: @SakisTsalk Yes I have tried that

Comment: Can you try this `const org = response.data;` and then `this.setState({org});` inside the `then()`

Comment: @SakisTsalk Sorry I tried that too. I did all the ideas which I can find in google is already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after taking a closer look at your `.jsx` code I noticed that your `.map()` operator is not returning anything so that's why nothing is displayed.

Please remove the brackets inside your `map()` arrow function and your org items will be correctly displayed.

Also as figured out previously you should probably assign `response.data` to your state object.

```js
 {this.state.persons.length > 0 && this.state.org.map((item, index) => 
                                <div class="col-sm-6 mb-5" key={index}>
                                    {item.name}
                                </div>
                            )}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. this works.. Can you give me a small explanation why we need to remove `{ `. Because I have worked with react projects before and I have used `{` everytime

Comment: Yes, you can keep the `{}` brackets but then you need to let the `map()` know which statement you want to return for each iteration. So in your case you should type `return <jsx />` if you want the brackets, which would make sense if you had more lines of code inside your map(). But since in javascript if you have a single statement inside an arrow function if you don't wrap the function in brackets it means that this single statement will be returned as well. I personally find that cleaner but that's up to you and your colleagues to choose what you prefer.

Comment: More info can be found here [link] (You can find more info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions